# Question about Html.BeginForm in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an HTML post method:

```
form method="post" action="https://secure.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/wcc/purchase" id="frmWorldPay"
```

How to write the above post method in the `<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>` syntax in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Upvoting because SLaks answer is good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

The `BeginForm()` method is designed to create `<form>` tags for MVC actions; it won't work with arbitrary URLs.

It won't help you anyway; it would just create exactly the same `<form>` tag as you already have.

Comment: ok I was thinking to write html.beginform for both the post form , but if the markup will be same , then there is no point

Comment: yeh i tried adding an alert to my second post=method.. the script is not even triggering that post